# From command line, how to open an URL in an existing Google Chrome window for a specific profile?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

From command line, how to open an URL in an existing Google Chrome window for a specific profile? By profiles, I mean https://linuxhint.com/use_multiple_profiles_simultaneously_google_chrome/.

Right now, if I simply do

```
open http://www.example.com
```

on Linux or

```
'C:\Users\xxx\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' http://www.example.com
```

on Windows (from Windows Terminal), it will open the URL in whatever Chrome window that happens to be "in focus" or "at the top" of the multiple windows I opened for different profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--profile-directory` option to specify which profile you want the URL to open in.

On macOS, this will open the URL `example.com` in `Profile 3`:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --profile-directory="Profile 3" https://example.com/
```

On Linux or Windows it is the same, but you have to provide the correct path to the Chrome program.

You can view the profile directory name at the special URL `chrome://version`, here's a [screenshot of where to find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsqgr.png).

If a profile has an email address associated with it, you can use `--profile-email=your@addre.ss` instead of `--profile-directory`.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, i use the following code in CMD to open a specific page in a specific profile. in this example, it's the default profile, but you can replace it with "Profile 3" just as easily.

```
Start chrome /profile-directory="Default" "http://www.example.com"
```